# Evaluating a Triple Integral of Sphere Centered at (1,2,3)

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, spherical-coordinates

I'm having trouble on a homework question evaluating $\int\int\int_D dxdydz$, where $D$ is the solid ball centered at $(1,2,3)$ with radius 4.

The professor suggested converting to spherical coordinates, but I guess that's what's throwing me off a bit.  Based on my notes I know $x=\rho\sin(\phi)\cos(\theta)$, $y=\rho\sin(\phi)\sin(\theta)$, and $z=\rho\cos(\phi)$.

I think my limits of integration will be $\int_0^\pi\int_0^{2\pi}\int_0^4$...$d\rho d\theta d\phi$, but I'm not sure what my integrand should be.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Hint: First write the equation of the given sphere then employ three change of variables before going to spherical coordinates.

Comment: You need to compute the jacobian of the change of variable matrix!

Comment: Did you realize that $$\iiint_{D} 1\,dx\,dy\,dz$$ is just the volume of $D$?